# Finding similarity measure between 2 plots..?

Tags: r, plot, similarity

sorry if my question sounds very amateurish..

Actually I have a set of plots in 2d form

Let X=(x1,x2...xn) be a set of similar plots obtained

```
Y=(y1,y2...yn) be a set of plots similar
```

[image]

Intuitively i can see that all plots of X 'look similar'  But how do i find the similarity between scores between 2 plots and prove that they have a high similarity score..??

I am using the R language... Can somebody help..??Thanks

Comment: first of all, your plots don't look similar at all. They just look like random sequences along an index of some sort. Second, this is a statistical question, and should be asked on http://www.crossvalidated.com. There are a number of techniques, but you'll have to provide more info about the nature of the data and the nature of the hypothesis.

Comment: Can't you just use correlations for this?

Comment: @Sacha : depending on what you want to know, yes. If you want to check general trends, correlations won't tell you much. You'll have to go to modeling for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are thinking of the case in which both plots have a value at any given position. Maybe this method will work:

For each index i, calculate (xi-yi)^2.
Sum over all i.
Divide by n.

This just calculates the average difference between points in the plot, so 0 would be exactly the same, while larger values mean less similarity. Statistically, there's probably a more accurately method, but this is a good estimate for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I may be a bit late here, but [FastDTW](http://cs.fit.edu/%7Epkc/papers/tdm04.pdf), an improvement on [Dynamic Time Warping](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74048-3_4) and implemented [here in python](https://pypi.org/project/fastdtw/) sounds like exactly what you need!